# Java Error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException"

Tags: java

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at IntegerSequence.main(IntegerSequence.java:73)
```

This is my first lab trying to read input from a text file and submit output to another text file. I need it to run 5 different 'for' loops. I thought I was close, and then I got the error. My code is as follows:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

    File myFile = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

    // set accumulator
    int sum = 0;

    double iterations = inputFile.nextDouble();

    for (int start = 1; start <= iterations; start++) { 

        int starting = inputFile.nextInt();
        int ending = inputFile.nextInt();

        for (starting = 0 + starting; starting <= ending; starting++) {

            sum = sum + starting;
        }
    }
    outputFile.println(iterations); 
    outputFile.println(sum);


    outputFile.close();
    inputFile.close();
        }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Post your input file. How are the numbers listed in there?

Comment: Why is `iterations` a floating point number? Is your file complete (has enough data for all iterations)?

Comment: OHH!! that makes sense! I'm very new to java. thank you.   But now It is not giving me the correct answers....       The input file is: 5   1   10   1   15

Comment: The documentation for `Scanner` says that the `nextInt()` method may throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the input is exhausted. Try using `hasNext()` before attempting a read.

Comment: Why you are using `nextDouble()` in iterations and what effect `starting = 0 + starting` will cause. Am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

> The input file is: 5 1 10 1 15

Your first number should be 2 then, since you only have two sets of `starting` and `ending` values. Or, you just need to provide three more pairs of values.

But, ideally you should program defensively with `hasNextXYZ()` checks for the kind of value you're about to read with a corresponding `nextXYZ()` read call or you run the risk of getting a `NoSuchElementException`.

Also, you're dealing exclusively with `int`s here. So, you should use `int` as the data type and call `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` only.

And since, `starting = 0 + starting;` seems to be doing nothing, the `for` loop can simply be

```
for (; starting <= ending; starting++) {
    sum += starting;
}
```

i.e. the *initialization* expression in a `for` loop is optional.

---

To calculate the sums separately instead of a cumulative total, you need to move the `sum` and it's associated `println()` calls to inside the loop.

```
int iterations = inputFile.nextInt();
outputFile.println(iterations); 

for (int start = 1; start <= iterations; start++) { 

    int starting = inputFile.nextInt();
    int ending = inputFile.nextInt();

    int sum = 0; // reset sum to 0

    for (; starting <= ending; starting++) {
        sum += starting;
    }
    outputFile.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but also, I need advice on how to make the output file display (2   55   120)   and it now displays ( 2   55   175) which is like a running total...I need the summations to be separate, if that makes sense.. thank you